# Script for a range of times in Python

Tags: python, url, time

I am attempting to get a script in Python to determine, from the system time, whether it should assign either 00, 06, 12, or 18 to a couple places in a URL. I assume this would be some type of range concerning time in Python.

Weather models run at certain times (00Z, 06Z, 12Z, and 18Z). Logically, they write their data to the URL's like this using those four times:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014052512/gfs.t12z.pgrb2f00

With that said, I would need my script to obey the following ranges.

- Get 00Z data between the hours of 00Z and 06Z (12AM and 6AM UTC
  Time).
- Get 06Z data between the hours of 06Z and 12Z (6AM and 12PM
  UTC Time).
- Get 12Z data between the hours of 12Z and 18Z (12PM and
  6PM UTC Time).
- Get 18Z data between the hours of 18Z and 00Z (6PM
  and 12AM UTC Time).

  It would need to assign the times to the following places in the URL, see the brackets

[http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.20140525[here]/gfs.t[here]z.pgrb2f00](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.20140525%5bhere%5d/gfs.t%5bhere%5dz.pgrb2f00)

I have the following for a script, however need integration of what is described above.

```
# Save your URL to a variable:
url = time.strftime("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.%Y%m%d00/gfs.t00z.pgrb2f00")

# Save that string to a file:
with open('filename', 'a') as f:
  f.write(url+'\n')
```

Any takers? Many thanks to those who respond!

Comment: Was originally referring to my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819258/script-for-a-changing-url/23819322#23819322, but I see now that it's the same OP... so it is a different question.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid Python code, it has many syntax errors.

Comment: this is pretty straight-forward: first you get the desired token `00Z`, `06Z` etc. by parsing the `datetime` and then you integrate it into the url like this: `format = "...%Y%m%d.."+token+"..."; url = time.strftime(format);` where's your attempt, where's your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The general outline would be similar to my answer in: [Script for a changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819258/script-for-a-changing-url/23819322#23819322)

But you can use `datetime.utcnow()` to get the current UTC time, and then use a series of `if-elif` blocks to specify your time ranges, setting a variable to the desired url time for each block depending on the time.